# Network call with RXJava and Retrofit correct implementation - Android

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2, okhttp, rx-android

I want to make a simple api call to user endpoint(register a new user) and get auth token with the response. Can anyone explain the difference between this two network calls and what implementation is the correct one in my case?

```
 private void registerProcess(User user) {
    mSubscriptions.add(Network.getRetrofit().getUserToken(user)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Response<TokenResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Response<TokenResponse> tokenResponse) {
                    if (tokenResponse.code() == 200) {
                        mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        showSnackBarMessage("Registration success!");
                    } else {
                        mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        showSnackBarMessage("Registration failed");
                    }

                }
            }));

}

 private void registerProcess(User user) {

    Network.getRetrofit().getUserToken(user)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<TokenResponse>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    /// what to do here???
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    showSnackBarMessage("Registration failed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Response<TokenResponse> tokenResponse) {
                  if (tokenResponse.code() == 200) {
                        mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        showSnackBarMessage("Registration success!");
                    } 
                }
            });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case:

- there is no `onError` callback handling, hence, for example, `IOException` will crash your app.

The second:

- subscription is not stored anywhere (unlike the first case), so it will leak if it's still running and not unsubscribed on activity's `onDestroy` callback for example.
- `onNext` handles only the successful response, so if there is HTTP code different from 200 nothing will happen.

The correct implementation is the fusion of these two snippets:

```
private void registerProcess(User user) {
    mSubscriptions.add(Network.getRetrofit().getUserToken(user)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response<TokenResponse>>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                // you might do nothing here
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                showSnackBarMessage("Error!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Response<TokenResponse> tokenResponse) {
                if (tokenResponse.code() == 200) {
                    mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    showSnackBarMessage("Registration success!");
                } else {
                    mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    showSnackBarMessage("Registration failed");
                } 
            }
        });
}
```

Don't forget to call `mSubscriptions.clear()` when activity (or fragment) is destroyed, to unsubscribe from all stored subscriptions.

**P.S.** You could utilize `doOnSubscribe` and `doAfterTerminate` operators, to set initial and terminal view states accordingly. For example to avoid multiple calls to `mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE)`:

```
mSubscriptions.add(Network.getRetrofit().getUserToken(user)
    .doOnSubscribe(() -> mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE))
    .doAfterterminate(() -> mProgressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE))
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Comment: ```.subscribe(new Action1<TokenResponse>() {

                    @Override
                    public void call(TokenResponse response) {
                        RegisterFragment.this.handleResponse(response);
                    }
                }, new Action1<Throwable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Throwable error) {
                        RegisterFragment.this.handleError(error);
                    }
``` Would that work?

Comment: Yeah, sure. You'll just loose the `onComplete` handling.